# Windows Azure AD Graph API, check if user is a shared mailbox

Tags: azure, office365, azure-ad-graph-api

Using the Windows Azure AD Graph REST API, specifically the `users` endpoint, is there a way to check if a returned user is a shared mailbox in Office365?

When using the powershell commandlet `Get-MsolUser` this can apparently be checked via the `CloudExchangeRecipientDisplayType` attribute, but that seems to be missing from the REST API. Is this exposed via the REST API somehow or is there another way to get that information?

Comment: Old post, but did you find a reasonable way to filter out SharedMailboxes? We need to one get OneDrive accounts so resorted to using Sku ids, however this isn't great because we had to list all the possible valid OneDrive sku ids (there are lots) and still finding missing ones